# Magento 2.3 - Using a Flat Catalog not recommended but much faster

Tags: magento2.3, magento2.3.5, flat-catalog, speedoptimization

We run a Magento 2.3.5 store with 125.000+ products. Magento no longer recommends to use flat catalog sinds 2.1.x (https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/catalog-flat.html)

But when we enable the flat catalog our entire store, especially the category and product page become much faster.

Load times drop from 1.5 ~ 2 seconds to 0.6 ~ 1.0 seconds.

Is there another way to achieve the same results, without enabling the flat catalog?

We are already running the store with Redis and Elasticsearch, production mode enabled and all JS/CSS settings.

The speed drop mentioned above, is with the same settings only the flat catalog enabled/disabled.

Comment: Use elasticsearch and disable flat catalog

Comment: @SohelRana Thanks! We already use Elasticsearch and even then it is much faster with flat catalog enabled. We still can not achieve the same loading speed without the flat catalog disabled.